# query through a database and displaying on cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a model that contains a list of sports. but the object I'm trying to call doesn't exist yet until I create the first one. so it is giving me red squigglies under the "LeaguebbM7and8" I believe im going about querying through it completely wrong since im new to c#.

the error reads:

```
'League' does not contain a definition for 'LeaguebbM7and8' and no accessible extension method 'LeaguebbM7and8' accepting a first argument of type 'League' could be found
```

my league model:

- int LeagueId { get; set; }
- string sport { get; set; }
- string gender { get; set; }
- string ageRange { get; set; }
- ​List<MMLeagueParticipant> allParticipants  { get; set; }        (a many to many relationship for league and participant)

my ViewModel model:

- ViewModelParticipant participant { get; set; }
- List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
- public class Participant

  - int ParticipantId { get; set; }
  - string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }
  - string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }
  - string ParticipantGender { get; set; }
  - SystemDateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }
  - List<MMLeagueParticipant> all Leagues { get; set; }

my MMLeagueParticipant middle table for the league model and ViewModel.Participant:

- int MMLeaugeParticipantId { get; set; }
- int ParticipantId { get; set; }
- int LeaugeId { get; set; }
- leauge sport { get; set; }
- ViewModel.Participant child { get; set; }

the following is how i would display the info on the page:

```
@model List<League>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM7and8-tab">
        7-8
        @{
            if(Model.LeaguebbM7and8 != null)
            {
                foreach(League i in Model)
                {
                    <p>@i.allParticipants.child.ParticipantFirstName @i.allParticipants.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                }
            }
            else if(Model.LeaguebbM7and8.Count == 0 || Model.LeaguebbM7and8 == null)
            {
                <p>the list is empty</p>
            }
        }
        </div>
</div>
```

what I'm trying to do:

- display all the first and lastnames of the the participants in certain age group if it exists. if it doesn't i want to display "empty list"

I am unsure if it has to do with the way im creating my league. following is how im going about it.

the way i add a new leauge:

- passing in an Id from some form
- if that Id exists it will check the gender and age
- depending on those checks the controller will either add it to an existing league or create the league and then add it (if the league doesn't exist yet)

  ```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("postNewBasketballPlayer")]
   public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer(int newParticipantId)
   {
       ViewModel.Participant newP = db.Participants.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ParticipantId == newParticipantId);
       if(newP != null)
       {    
           var timespan = DateTime.Now - newP.ParticipantDOB;
           //this block of code is also repeated for newP.ParticipantGender == "Female"
           if(newP.ParticipantGender == "Male")
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Male basketball player");
                   //this block of code repeates for different age groups
                   if(timespan.TotalDays>=(7*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(9*365))
                   {
                       League LeaguebbM7and8 = db.Leagues.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.gender == "Male" && i.ageRange == "7and8" && i.sport == "Basketball");
                       //if the League doesn't exist it creates it
                       if(LeaguebbM7and8 == null)
                       {
                           LeaguebbM7and8 = new League()
                           {
                               sport = "Basketball",
                               gender = "Male",
                               ageRange = "7and8"
                           };
                           db.Add(LeaguebbM7and8);
                           db.SaveChanges();
                           Console.WriteLine("made new league LeaguebbM7and8");

                           MMLeagueParticipant MMbbM7and8 = new MMLeagueParticipant()
                           {
                               ParticipantId = newParticipantId,
                               LeagueId = LeaguebbM7and8.LeagueId
                           };
                           //adds a row to table with the id's
                           db.Add(MMbbM7and8);
                           db.SaveChanges();
                           Console.WriteLine("added to LeaguebbM7and8");
                       }
                       //if the league exists; it simply adds it. 
                       else
                       {
                           //each time i add a child. it needs its own middle table (reason for new)
                           MMLeagueParticipant MMbbM7and8 = new MMLeagueParticipant()
                           {
                               ParticipantId = newParticipantId,
                               LeagueId = LeaguebbM7and8.LeagueId
                           };
                           db.Add(MMbbM7and8);
                           db.SaveChanges();
                           Console.WriteLine("added to LeaguebbM7and8");
                       }
                       Console.WriteLine("returning to dashboard (LeaguebbM7and8)");
                       return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
                   }
                   //this code is repeated for multiple age checks as above.
                   //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(9*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(11*365)){...}
                   //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(11*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(13*365)){...}
                   //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(13*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(15*365)){...}
                   //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(15*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(17*365)){...}
                   //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(17*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(19*365)){...}
               }
           //repeates the block of code above for all the age check if female.
           //if(newP.ParticipantGender == "Female)...
       }
       if(newP == null)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("id passed in was null");
           return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
       }
       Console.WriteLine("skips all if checks because newP was null");
       return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
   }
  ```

the following would be how I would call roaster page and send the list in as a model:
the List would be all the leagues that contain basketball as my sport.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("roster/basketball")]
public IActionResult BasketballRoster()
{
    List<League> allBasketballLeagues = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport =="Basketball").ToList();
    return View("RosterPageBasketball", allBasketballLeagues);
}
```

Comment: Hi @jgrewal, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you confirm that your error message is not `'List<League>' does not contain a definition for 'LeaguebbM7and8' and no accessible extension method 'LeaguebbM7and8' accepting a first argument of type 'List<League>' could be found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ISSUE

In your page, your `Model` is `List` type. Thus you cannot access `LeaguebbM7and8` from `List`.

```
@model List<League>
```

---

### SOLUTION

1. You should do in this way to check List is not null and not Empty

```
Model != null && Model.Any()
```

2. **[UPDATED]** As your `League` class contains `allParticipants` which is `List<MMLeagueParticipant>` type, you have to use `foreach` loop to access each `MMLeagueParticipant` element.

```
foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in i.allParticipants)
```

Your .cshtml page should be:

```
@model List<League>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM7and8-tab">
        7-8
        @{
            if (Model != null && Model.Any())
            {
                foreach(League i in Model)
                {
                    foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in i.allParticipants)
                    {
                        <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                    }  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <p>the list is empty</p>
            }
        }
        </div>
</div>
```

FYI,

1. `.Any()` return true when the `IEnumerable` object has at least 1 element, it is equivalent to `.Count() > 0`.
2. Switch `else if` to `else` as it validates the `Model` is neither `null` nor empty list. It will proceed to `else` statement if fail to fulfill the `if` statement.

Comment: Im still getting an issue querying through and displaying the first and last names. i tried @i.LeaguebbM7and8.allParticipants.child.ParticipantFirstName

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You have to use `@i.allParticipants.child.ParticipantFirstName`. `i` is a `League` type and your `League` class doesn't contain `LeaguebbM7and8` property.

Comment: the child part gives me the following error 'List<MMLeagueParticipant>' does not contain a definition for 'child' and no accessible extension method 'child' accepting a first argument of type 'List<MMLeagueParticipant>' could be found '. Even though I have child in my MMLeagueParticcipants.cs. The other issue is I only want to display the participants that are in the age group of 7and8. I'm thinking I should query through the database where i created the new league instead of the foreach (league i in model). Unsure how to go about that.

Comment: Hi @jgrewal, sorry about that, I have updated my answer, as your `allParticipants` is `List<MMLeagueParticipant>` type, you have to use `foreach` loop to retrieve every `MMLeagueParticipant` object.

Comment: For your second issue, you can use `.Where()` to filter `ageRange` for your desired criteria in `BasketballRoster` method.